# How to preg_replace or str_replace '][' or '] [' with 'BR'

Tags: preg-replace, str-replace

I have something like this:

```
[shortcode] text [/shortcode] [shortcode_2] text [/shortcode_2][button] [shortcode_3] text [/shortcode_3] [image] text
```

How do I preg_replace (or str_replace) so `<br />` gets inserted between each
`']['` or `'] ['`

**EDIT:**

In order to make things as clear as possible...

input:

```
[shortcode] text [/shortcode] [shortcode_2] text [/shortcode_2][button] [shortcode_3] text [/shortcode_3] [image] text
```

output:

```
[shortcode]<br />text<br />[/shortcode]<br />[shortcode_2]<br />text<br />[/shortcode_2]<br />[button]<br />[shortcode_3]<br />text<br />[/shortcode_3]<br />[image]<br />text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `preg_replace_callback`

```
$r = preg_replace_callback('/\]([^\]]+)?(\[)|([^\]]+$)/', function($matches) {

    var_dump($matches);

    if (!strlen($matches[1])) {
        return "";
    } else if (!isset($matches[1]) || !strlen(trim($matches[1]))) {
        return "]<br />[";
    } else {
        return "]<br />" . trim($matches[1]) . "<br />[";
    }

}, '[shortcode] text [/shortcode] [shortcode_2] text [/shortcode_2][button] [shortcode_3] text [/shortcode_3] [image] text');
```

Comment: Thanks! Would it be hard for you to explain a little bit, I have no experience with regular expressions. And yeah, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Well, I tested with your input and is working fine: https://eval.in/56141. As you can se a `<br />` is inserted between `][`. The regex simply matches `]` - `a space or nothing` - `[`

Comment: Yes, it's working fine but only partially. My bad, I realized I wasn't clear enough, I have updated my question, hopefully it does make sense now. Thanks for you efforts!

Comment: Awesome! I would never be able to figure that out, thanks a lot!